# Could not access pid file for elasticsearch

Tags: ubuntu, init.d, elasticsearch, pid

I am not a die-hard linux engineer, but I am having some problems with starting Elastic Search. Some stats:

Server: Ubuntu Server 11.04
Elastic Search: 1.2.3 (installed with appitude)

When I start Elastic Search it 'starts'without an error:

`* Starting Elasticsearch Server`

(Over and over again)

When I run status I get:

`* could not access PID file for elasticsearch`

The pid file located here has the right permissions (I guess?):

`-rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch 0 2014-08-11 12:26 /var/run/elasticsearch.pid`

Also the elasticsearch user exists in the /etc/passwd file. I also tried to purge elastic search and install it over again but that didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the output of:
`id elasticsearch` ?

Comment: `uid=113(elasticsearch) gid=115(elasticsearch) groups=115(elasticsearch)` Seems right?

Comment: Looks right, I think you should start looking for an error log (/var/log/messages or a specific if there is one for elasticsearch). Maybe the error you get from status is just misleading...

Comment: Thanks. I am searching, but the /var/log/elasticsearch folder is empty and I don't have /var/log/messages. Also checked syslog but nothing usefull found.

Comment: What does the pidfile contain? Have you tried deleting it to let it be recreated?

Comment: It's an empty file, and I deleted it more then once but unfortunetly it didn't help..

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that somehow I managed to install a ElasticSearch version which required Java 7 (openjdk-7-*) which isn't support for Ubuntu 11.04.

The reason I wanted to update is because of a vulnerability which makes your server usable for DDOS attacks.

I finally fixed the problem by downgrading Elastic Search to version 1.1.2 and adding firewall rules to my iptables.